# Can't access PlayerGui in ServerScript when a purchase is completed

Tags: roblox

So, I want to make if a Player succesfully donate in my game, an GUi will show up in the Player screen with a Tween Animation that says Purchase is completed

When I tested it out, I expected when I trying to test to purchase donate, it will show up a GUi, But, the actual results is already showed up in Output. When I tried to playtest it, An error `ServerScriptService.Purchases:14: attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'` showed up in Output

I already searched on Google and still can't understand.

Here's the code:

```
-- Products for purchases
local Donate1ProductID = 1296480045
local Donate2ProductID = 1296484976
local Donate3ProductID = 1296484935
local Donate4ProductID = 1296484932
local Donate5ProductID = 1296483595
local Donate6ProductID = 1296484931
local Donate7ProductID = 1296484933

-- Required depencies/services
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local LocalPlayer = Players.LocalPlayer
local Main = LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui"):WaitForChild("AntiPiracyCheck")

-- Code
MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt = function(receiptInfo)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerByUserId(receiptInfo.PlayerId)

    if receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate1ProductID or Donate2ProductID or Donate3ProductID or Donate4ProductID or Donate5ProductID or Donate6ProductID or Donate7ProductID then
        Main.PurchaseSuccess:TweenPosition(
            UDim2.new(0.258, 0,0.279, 0),
            Enum.EasingDirection.InOut,
            Enum.EasingStyle.Quad,
            1,
            true
        )
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's a server script LocalPlayer doesn't exist therefore it's a nil value.

```
-- Products for purchases
local Donate1ProductID = 1296480045
local Donate2ProductID = 1296484976
local Donate3ProductID = 1296484935
local Donate4ProductID = 1296484932
local Donate5ProductID = 1296483595
local Donate6ProductID = 1296484931
local Donate7ProductID = 1296484933

-- Required depencies/services
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")


-- Code
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(LocalPlayer)
MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt = function(receiptInfo)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerByUserId(receiptInfo.PlayerId)
    local Main = player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui"):WaitForChild("AntiPiracyCheck")
    if receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate1ProductID or Donate2ProductID or Donate3ProductID or Donate4ProductID or Donate5ProductID or Donate6ProductID or Donate7ProductID then
        Main.PurchaseSuccess:TweenPosition(
            UDim2.new(0.258, 0,0.279, 0),
            Enum.EasingDirection.InOut,
            Enum.EasingStyle.Quad,
            1,
            true
        )
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted

   end
end
```

Comment: server Scripts can't access the PlayerGui, only LocalScripts can. The server Script needs to process the receipt and then use RemoteEvents to communicate to the LocalScript to show the animation.

Comment: Ok. I get it now how to use RemoteEvents.