# No functions were fired when Firing RemoteEvents

Tags: roblox

So, I want to make if a purchase is completed, a GUI will appear

[@x72 is already answered it but I don't use her codes. I tried to use another code but didn't work either.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73372620/cant-access-playergui-in-serverscript-when-a-purchase-is-completed)

I didn't get it work but no error messages

Here's the code:

Script:

```
-- Products for purchases
local Donate1ProductID = 1296480045
local Donate2ProductID = 1296484976
local Donate3ProductID = 1296484935
local Donate4ProductID = 1296484932
local Donate5ProductID = 1296483595
local Donate6ProductID = 1296484931
local Donate7ProductID = 1296484933

-- Required depencies/services
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local PurchaseSuccess = ReplicatedStorage.PurchaseSuccess

-- Code
MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt = function(receiptInfo)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerByUserId(receiptInfo.PlayerId)

    if receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate1ProductID or Donate2ProductID or then Donate3ProductID or Donate4ProductID or Donate5ProductID or Donate6ProductID or Donate7ProductID then
        PurchaseSuccess:FireAllClients()
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
    end
end
```

LocalScript:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local PurchaseSuccess = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("PurchaseSuccess")
local playerGui = player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
local Main = playerGui:WaitForChild("AntiPiracyCheck")

PurchaseSuccess.OnClientEvent:Connect(function ()
    Main.PurchaseSuccess:TweenPosition(
        UDim2.new(0.258, 0,0.279, 0),
        Enum.EasingDirection.InOut,
        Enum.EasingStyle.Quad,
        1,
        true
    )
end)
```

What is the problem anyway?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting any error messages in the Output window? You've got a syntax error in your server Script's if-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your server Script's if-statement, that might be why nothing is happening. You have a stray `then` in the middle of the condition list, and it should only be at the end.

When using an if-statement to check whether a condition is true, you need to be explicit.

```lua
if receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate1ProductID or Donate2ProductID or Donate3ProductID or Donate4ProductID or Donate5ProductID or Donate6ProductID or Donate7ProductID then
```

This if-statement is saying, "if the receipt's productId matches Donate1ProductID, do a thing. Or if Donate2ProductID exists, do a thing. Or if Donate3ProductID exists, do a thing..." You aren't asking if the receipt's productID matches any of the listed product ids, you are only asking if the other product ids exist. You need to explicitly ask if `receiptInfo.ProductID == [THE_PRODUCT_ID]` in each case...

```lua
if receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate1ProductID or
    receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate2ProductID or
    receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate3ProductID or
    receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate4ProductID or
    receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate5ProductID or
    receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate6ProductID or
    receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate7ProductID then
```

But there is a nicer way to do that, you can put all of the ids as the keys of a table and check if the receipt matches any of the known keys. Try something like this :

```lua
-- Products for purchases mapped to a message about it.
local donationIDMap = {
    [1296480045] = "Donated X amount",
    [1296484976] = "Donated X amount",
    [1296484935] = "Donated X amount",
    [1296484932] = "Donated X amount",
    [1296483595] = "Donated X amount",
    [1296484931] = "Donated X amount",
    [1296484933] = "Donated X amount",
}

-- Required depencies/services
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local PurchaseSuccess = ReplicatedStorage.PurchaseSuccess

-- Code
MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt = function(receiptInfo)
    local player = Players:GetPlayerByUserId(receiptInfo.PlayerId)
    
    local donationMessage = donationIDMap[receiptInfo.ProductId]
    local messageExists = donationMessage ~= nil
    if messageExists then
        -- you could send the message to the client so they know that it worked..
        PurchaseSuccess:FireClient(player, donationMessage)
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
    end

    -- not sure what they bought.
    local message = "NO HANDLER SPECIFIED FOR PRODUCT ID : %d. %s DID NOT RECEIVE ANYTHING FOR THIS PURCHASE.":format(receiptInfo.ProductId, player.Name)
    warn(message)
    return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
end
```

Then on the client you can optionally handle the message from the server like this...

```lua
PurchaseSuccess.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(donationMessage)
    -- put the message into a textbox...
    -- local txtBox = Main.Purchased.Message -- find the path to some ui element
    -- txtBox.Text = donationMessage
```

Comment: The `if` isn't syntactically incorrect, it's more of an incorrect logic problem.

Comment: @Random, They have a stray `then` in the middle of the if-statement. If you reduce it down to just `if true or then`, you'll see that it throws an "unexpected symbol near 'then'" error.

Comment: Wait what? I didn't realize I have a then in the middle of if statement. What I meant is ```if receiptInfo.ProductId == Donate1ProductID or Donate2ProductID or Donate3ProductID or Donate4ProductID or Donate5ProductID or Donate6ProductID or Donate7ProductID then```

Comment: Maybe still doesn't work too.

Comment: or the problem was I put my LocalScript in ReplicatedStorage..

Comment: IT WAS!!! OMG I DIDNT REALIZE THAT. THANK YOU MYSELF.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, Your LocalScript was in **REPLICATEDSTORAGE.**